# sucesión de 4 caracteres aleatorios hasta formar una palabra c++

Tags: c++

estoy haciendo un programa en el que el usuario ingresa una palabra de 4 caracteres y el sistema
debe ejecutar secuencias aleatorias hasta hacer coincidir con la palabra.

Ya puedo generar las letras aleatoriamente pero no sé como hacer otro ciclo para que se detenga cuando vuelva a aparecer la palabra.
Agradezco su ayuda..

```
    int main()
   {
    const int tamano=4;

    srand(time(NULL));
    int cont=0,i;
    char arre[tamano];

    printf ("Ingrese una palabra de 4 letras: \n");

    gets (arre);
    while(1)
    {

        for(int contador = 0; contador<tamano; contador++) 

            printf("%c",arre[rand() %4]);

               printf ("\n");

    Sleep (1000);
   }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Lo primero, si necesitas almacenar cadenas de caracteres de longitud `N`, los arrays deben tener de tamaño, al menos, `N+1`. No olvides que las cadenas de caracteres en C++ finalizan **siempre** con `'\0'`.

```
const int tamano = 5; // no 4
```

Por otro lado, si tienes que manejar 2 cadenas de caracteres a la vez (la introducida por el usuario y la aleatoria), necesitas forzosamente dos variables:

```
char usuario[tamano];
char aleatoria[tamano];
```

Además, suele ser una buena recomendación inicializar las variables. Así no nos tendremos que preocupar de asignar el caracter nulo de final de cadena a mano:

```
char usuario[tamano]   = {'\0'}; // Ponemos todos los bytes a 0
char aleatoria[tamano] = {'\0'}; // Ponemos todos los bytes a 0
```

Ya podemos pedirle al usuario su palabra mágica. Aprovechamos para hacer uso de la entrada/salida propia de C++ y olvidar la heredada de C:

```
std::cout << "Ingrese una palabra de " << (tamano-1) << "letras\n";
std::cin >> usuario;
```

Ahora lo que vamos a hacer es almacenar la palabra aleatoria en `aleatoria`. Este paso es necesario ya que posteriormente necesitarás saber si ambas palabras coinciden.

```
for(int contador = 0; contador<tamano; contador++) 
{
  aleatoria[contador] = usuario[rand()%tamano];
}
std::cout << aleatoria << '\n';
```

Ya tenemos las dos palabras... vamos a compararlas:

```
do
{
    for(int contador = 0; contador<tamano; contador++) 
    {
      aleatoria[contador] = usuario[rand()%tamano];
    }
    std::cout << aleatoria << '\n';
} while( strcmp(usuario, aleatoria) != 0 );
```

Claro que lo mismo queda todo más claro si reemplazamos `char[]` por `std::string`:

```
std::string usuario, aleatoria;

do
{
    std::cout << "Ingrese una palabra de " << (tamano-1) << "letras\n";
    std::cin >> usuario;
}
while( usuario.length() != tamano );

do
{
    aleatoria = ""; // Reiniciamos la palabra aleatoria

    for(int contador = 0; contador<tamano; contador++) 
    {
        aleatoria += usuario[rand()%tamano];
    }
    std::cout << aleatoria << '\n';
} while( usuario != aleatoria );
```

Vaya, parece que si ejecuto el programa varias veces, las secuencias *aleatorias* que genera son siempre las mismas... ¿y eso?

Bueno, eso sucede porque se te ha olvidado inicializar el generador de números aleatorios:

```
std::string usuario, aleatoria;

srand(time(NULL));

do
{
    // ...
```

De esta forma, el generador se inicializará con una semilla que consiste en una marca de tiempo que coincide con la hora actual del sistema... cada ejecución tendrá su propia marca y, en consecuencia, las palabras que se generen serán diferentes.

Claro que `rand()` es otra característica heredada de C que no funciona demasiado bien... ojo que para lo que tu tienes que hacer cumple su misión... pero en C++ hay herramientas mejores en la librería `random`.

```
std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 mt(rd());
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(0, tamano-1);

// ...

aleatoria[contador] = usuario[mt(dist)];
```

Donde:

- `std::random_device` es un generador de números aleatorios. El problema que tiene este generador es que es demasiado lento, así que normalmente se utiliza para inicializar un generador de números más ligero.
- `std::mt19937` es otro generador de números aleatorios. Es mucho más rápido que el anterior pero a cambio necesita que se le pase una semilla inicial.
- `std::uniform_int_distribution<>`: Esta plantilla sirve para forzar a que los números aleatorios se encuentren dentro del rango que nosotros necesitamos. A diferencia del uso del operador `%`, esta clase garantiza que todos los números de la distribución tienen la misma probabilidad de salir.

Answer (score 1):

Primero decirte que si la cadena tiene que ser de 4 letras, no puedes reservar 4 caracteres sino 5, porque necesitas el final de cadena que te va a escribir la función `gets` cuando termines de teclear en la consola. Así que estás pisando memoria que no es tuya y el resultado es imprevisible. Tu array tiene que ser de 5.

Y después en el bucle `for`, en vez de imprimir, puedes guardar cada carácter aleatorio en otra cadena. Cuando termine el `for`, solo tendrías que comparar la cadena generada aleatoriamente con la original. Si es igual, sales del `while`. Algo así:

```
char szTemp[ tamano + 1];
int contador = 0;
while(1)
{

    for(contador = 0; contador < tamano; contador++) {

        szTemp[ contador] = arre[ rand() % 4];
    }
    szTemp[ contador] = '\0'; //Añadimos el fin de línea en la cadena generada.
    if( strcmp( arre, szTemp) == 0) {
        printf( "Cadena encontrada: %s\n", szTemp);
        break; //Sale del bucle while porque ya ha terminado.
    } else {
        printf( "No hay coincidencia de momento. Cadena generada: %s.\n", szTemp);
    }
}
```

Comment: Por eso le he dicho que tiene que aumentar el array original

Answer (score 0):

Has etiquetado la pregunta como [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), pero tu código es [c](/questions/tagged/c). Voy a responder siguiendo tu etiqueta, no tu código:

- En lugar de formaciones de `char`, usaremos `std::string`.
- En lugar de `rand`, usaremos las utilidades de la cabecera `<random>`.

Suponiendo que disponemos de una función que nos devuelve palabras aleatorias de cuatro letras:

```
std::string palabra_aleatoria()
{
    static std::random_device dispositivo;
    static std::mt19937 generador(dispositivo());
    static std::uniform_int_distribution<char> distribucion('a', 'z');

    std::string resultado(4, '\0');
    std::generate(resultado.begin(), resultado.end(),
    []() { return distribucion(generador); });

    return resultado;
}
```

Un bucle que intente palabras hasta acertar la que pusiste podría ser este:

```
std::cout << "Ingrese una palabra de cuatro letras: \n";
std::cin >> palabra;

for (auto intento = palabra_aleatoria(); intento != palabra; intento = palabra_aleatoria())
{
    std::cout << "Intento adivinar tu palabra con " << intento << '\n';
}
```

Si te fijas, el generador de palabras aleatorias sólo genera palabras con todas las letras en minúsculas, así que para que la validación sea correcta deberías pasar a minúsculas la entrada del usuario:

```
std::transform(palabra.begin(), palabra.end(), palabra.begin(),
    [](auto c) { return std::tolower(c); });
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZJPaxsxEMXP1qeYuIfVQmpSGijxOgbfWmibSy@hLmYsqWvBerToj1Ma/Nnd2ayttdvQ0y5Pv3kzeiPVtm9Vg1QfDm8sqSZpAzPrQvQGt3MxaKxYqs8Vj6TdBYNN7byNGxZFiHo67YugxQbXHlfYGIxMoCzFsxiFiNEqeCF7s5U2O6sMaBtaF2y0O1ddctv47u7u/QeoDRmP2nl5xsqy/AtPZH86v11ZiisGeZx1itbRjIU5nBTFiiywuIbid8EWnccwvTchNZF7yVsGljdF34SBfohoZEYma1NbkuX1UDUxpDvh@w9ZwjPrMXm6bJ0vU1awf@l/pLJJJfZC8Mywxc6@S085CtH8aj0kCrYmo@Hb4svi6@MD3MNtqi4vcVxB562dGHF9f6xcijCbwfgT1dzNsBmeYOCdqoTRO2hM9BimsKRxlUstwXw@OI/28LSxjQF5lCaNoTpu@NpXPNGQK1tR6NaSwZzaSThm9s85h4gpOlBnUfaernFPxkuVI@QG0MOcmyH@3r/2EKt8fJXPq/@XlK/n11egtjtL6CGmnCOvCsYddbLl32JJRZfZsOwbXvLh0CI/XxQfHz4vxB8)</kbd>.